# How can I connect the paths of two ojects?

Tags: python, opencv, scipy, signals

I have time series data for the position of two objects. The second object roughly follows the path of the first object. I want to join the two objects with a curved line that best represents the combined paths of the two objects. This is post-processing, so I already know the future paths of both objects. I can use information about where the second object will be to compute the path. [Link to .csv file of source data in Google Drive - blue is columns 0,1 and yellow is columns 3,4.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QZYZSlmsjF441qNc4Nc5YoK1GLxl8GMf)

My source data looks like this:

[image: yellow following blue]

The objects are spaced fairly equally. Object two reaches the position of object one in around 50 frames. My initial approach was to take the past 25 frames of object blue object, and the future 25 frames of the yellow object. I used `signal.savgol()` to smooth the results (shown in pink).

```
positions = leading_object[frame_number - 25: frame_number]
positions += trailing_object[frame_number: frame_number + 25
x,y = zip(*positions)
window_length = int(len(x)*.5)
if window_length//2 == window_length/2: window_length -= 1
x = signal.savgol_filter(x, window_length, polyorder)
y = signal.savgol_filter(y, window_length, polyorder)
positions = list(zip(x,y))
```

[image: path]

This works okay, but the smoothed line *jogs* from one path to another. I'd like the path to be smooth.

[image: actual vs desired]

[Link to complete code used to generate animations.](https://github.com/smeschke/juggling/blob/master/tracking_object_writer_path.py)

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially trying to do curve fitting for a curve that joins the two positions and interpolates some points of the two lines. As things stand the problem is a little overdetermined in that you have rather too many points. This leads to 'kinks' in the curve.

Perhaps choosing fewer points e.g. 5th, 10th, 15th of each partial trajectory to give 6 points plus your fixed endpoints would work better.

I would then choose a curve fitting strategy that gives good continuity for the derivatives such as a non uniform rational B-spline (NURB) or maybe a Chebyshev polynomial.